# Llamando a una funcion dentro de la misma clase en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, class

Estoy intentando llamar a una funcion dentro de la misma clase en javascript pero me arroja error:

El método que intento llamar es **getDetalle**(). La idea es llamar a ese método dentro de otro método de la clase.

> "Cannot read property 'getDetalle' of undefined"

```
class InformesCtrl {

    constructor(){

    }

    async getPersonas(req, res){

        try {

            const { RESPUESTA: VISITAS, ERROR } = await data.getVisitas(req.body)

            if(ERROR) throw { message: 'Ocurrió un error.'}
      
            if(VISITAS.length > 0){
                var VISITA_DETALLE = this.getDetalle(VISITAS) //Método en la misma clase
            }

        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error)           
        }
    }

    async getDetalle (VISITAS) {
       return await Promise.all(
            VISITAS.map(async (visita) =>{

                const res = await data.getDetelleVisita(visita.ID_VISITA)
                return {...visita, DETALLE:res.RESPUESTA}

            })
        )
    }
 }
```

Comment: ¿Cómo llamas al método `getPersonas`?

Comment: Aunque no tiene que ver con el error, `construnctor` está mal escrito.

Comment: Pero el error se refiere a algo llamado `getDetalleV` y en el código que muestras no hay nada llamado así, seguro está todo el código relevante? también veo un `data` que no es muy claro de donde sale

Comment: @PabloLozano muchas gracias. Por aquí estaba el problema. Sólo fue cuestión de cambiar el método getPersona a tipo arrow function. Y con eso no tuve necesidad de agregar en el constructor el bind(this.) Muchas gracias.

Comment: Un placer, siempre es reconfortante encontrar uno mismo la causa y solución de estos problemas con una pequeña pista :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así quedó la solución, básicamente fue cambiar el método padre getPersonas a arrow function.
Lo mismo el método getDetalle.

```
class InformesCtrl {

       getPersonas = async (req, res)=> {
           try {
               const { RESPUESTA: VISITAS, ERROR } = await        data.getVisitas(req.body)

               if(ERROR) throw { message: 'Ocurrió un error.'}
      
               if(VISITAS.length > 0){
                   var VISITA_DETALLE = this.getDetalle(VISITAS) //Método en la misma clase
               }

           } catch (error) {
             console.log(error)           
           }
       }

       getDetalle = async  (VISITAS) => {
           return await Promise.all(
               VISITAS.map(async (visita) =>{

                   const res = await        data.getDetelleVisita(visita.ID_VISITA)
                   return {...visita, DETALLE:res.RESPUESTA}

               })
           )
       } 
   }
```